# AttributeError: 'ColumnTransformer' object has no attribute 'get_feature_names_out'

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn, google-colaboratory

I have this:

Preprocessing

```
numeric_transformer = Pipeline(
    steps=[("imputer",SimpleImputer(strategy="mean")), ("scaler", StandardScaler())] 
)
num=['hrs', 'absences', 'JobInvolvement', 'PerformanceRating', 'EnvironmentSatisfaction', 'JobSatisfaction', 'WorkLifeBalance', 'Age', 'DistanceFromHome', 'Education', 'EducationField', 'JobLevel', 'JobRole', 'MonthlyIncome', 'NumCompaniesWorked', 'PercentSalaryHike', 'StockOptionLevel', 'TotalWorkingYears', 'TrainingTimesLastYear', 'YearsAtCompany', 'YearsSinceLastPromotion', 'YearsWithCurrManager']
categorical_transformer=Pipeline(
    steps=[("imputer",SimpleImputer(strategy="most_frequent")), ("OE", OrdinalEncoder())]  # DROP IF BINARY?
) 
cat= ['BusinessTravel', 'Department', 'Gender', 'MaritalStatus']
preprocessor = ColumnTransformer(transformers=[
        ("numericals", numeric_transformer, num),
        ("categoricals", categorical_transformer,cat )   ], remainder='passthrough')
```

Function to simplify

```
def mod(a,b):
  model = Pipeline(
      steps=[("preprocessing", preprocessor), ("select", a),("clf", b)])
  return model
```

Starting to create the model

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.33, random_state=100431219) 
clf=mod(SelectKBest(chi2),RandomForestClassifier()) # preprocessing, select, clf

param_grid = {'preprocessing__numericals__imputer__strategy': ['mean'],
        'preprocessing__numericals__scaler': [MinMaxScaler()],
        'preprocessing__categoricals__imputer__strategy': ['most_frequent'],
        'select__k': list(range(1,14))}

inner = KFold(n_splits=7, shuffle=True, random_state=100431219)

clf = GridSearchCV(clf,
                            param_grid, 
                            scoring='accuracy',
                            cv=inner, 
                            n_jobs=4, verbose=1,
                        )
np.random.seed(100431219)
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

And here I got the error:

```
trained_pipeline = clf.best_estimator_

print(f"Features selected: {trained_pipeline.named_steps['select'].get_support()}")

print(f"Locations where features selected: {np.where(trained_pipeline.named_steps['select'].get_support())}")

# Feature names before selection (i.e. after preprocessing)
feature_names_before_selection = trained_pipeline.named_steps['preprocessing'].get_feature_names_out() # In this line is the error 
print(f"In Scikit-learn 1.x, we can even get the feature names after selection: {trained_pipeline.named_steps['select'].get_feature_names_out(feature_names_before_selection)}")
```

I obtained the number of features, their positions but not their names. I want the names

Comment: What is your python version? `get_feature_names_out` is a new names, I believed used since 1.0.0
Previously I think it was named `get_feature_names`

Comment: Doing !python  --version -> Python 3.8.16

Comment: Excuse me, I meant the sklearn version, not Python.

Comment: oh okay, it is 0.24.2

Answer (score 0):

As you are using sklearn version 2.24 you should be referring to specific docs.
Have a look at this link https://scikit-learn.org/0.24/modules/generated/sklearn.compose.ColumnTransformer.html?highlight=get_feature_names#sklearn.compose.ColumnTransformer.get_feature_names

It says that there is a method `ColumnTransformer.get_feature_names`. There is no such method `get_feature_names.

For more information about this change you can have a look here https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/pull/18444

The likely fix to your issue is using this code:

```
feature_names_before_selection = trained_pipeline.named_steps['preprocessing'].get_feature_names()
```

Comment: Thank you, but now I got this: AttributeError: Transformer numericals (type Pipeline) does not provide get_feature_names.

Comment: Also tried this: clf.best_estimator_.named_steps.preprocessing.get_feature_names()
and the same error: AttributeError: Transformer numericals (type Pipeline) does not provide get_feature_names.